# How to aggregate between multiple indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I was wondering if anyone could help me with my problem:

I have a template and the number of indices is mapped using the template.
i.e.
cdr_xyz_1234
cdr_xyz_5689
cdr_xyz_9876

I run a search query on all the indices and it works fine
GET cdr_xyz_*/_search

but if I run an aggregate search query

GET cdr_xyz_*/_serach

I get "request [/cdr_xyz_*/_serach/] contains unrecognized parameter: [expand_wildcards]"

I even created a user with the role which has "cdr_xyz_*" all privileges but still get the same error.
Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: Hello, I find no difference between the search query (GET cdr_xyz_*/_search) and the aggregate search query (GET cdr_xyz_*/_serach), also you have a type in the aggregate search query you put serach instead of search

Comment: Thanks Diego serach was a mistype in here.

Comment: This is the search {
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "call_datetime_iso": {
              "gte": "2019-11-20"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: and this is the aggregate search {  "size" : 0,
  "query": 
  {"bool": 
      {"must": 
              [ 
           {"match": {"call_type": "MOBILE"}}
          ]
      }
  },
  "aggs": 
    {"account": 
      {"terms": {"field": "accountid.keyword"}, 
        "aggs": 
          {"calls_over_time": 
            {"date_histogram": 
              {"field": "call_datetime_iso", "interval": "week"}
            }
          }
      }
    }
}